# Conditionally render some text based on state changes only working when I refresh my page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to conditionally render some text after a state is updated.

I start off defining 4 states. My function sends a `POST` request to an api, which returns a prediction based on ML model. I then update states to indicate who won according to my ML model.

So if userA wins I either receive 'userAW or 'userBL'. If it is a tie I receive 'Draw', if userB wins I either receive 'userBW' or 'userAL'.

I update the state outcome with this result. Based on what is in the outcome state, I update the states winnerA and winnerB based on who won.

If winnerA is true this means userA won, if winnerB is true this means userB won.

In the return statement I would like to check for the output in winnerA and winnerB and return text indicating whether the particular user won, lost or drew:

```
const outcome = useRef([])
const winnerA = useRef([])
const tie = useRef([])
const winnerB = useRef([])

function getPrediction(data) {
      const sending  = {}
      sending['challenge'] = fighters
      axios.post('http://******/predict', sending, {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
      })
        .then((res) => {
          const outcomes = ["userAW", "userBW", "Draw", "Draw", "userAL", "userBL"]
          const poss = [res.data[0][0]*100, res.data[0][1]*100, res.data[1][0]*100, res.data[1][1]*100, res.data[2][0]*100, res.data[2][1]*100]
          let randomVal = Math.random() * 100;
          let runningSum = 0
          for(let i = 0; i < poss.length; i++){
            runningSum += poss[i];
            if(randomVal <= runningSum){
              outcome.current = outcomes[i]
              if(outcome.current === 'userAW' || outcome.current === 'userBL'){
                console.log('one')
                winnerA.current = true
              }
              else if(outcome.current === 'Draw'){
                console.log('two')
                tie.current = true
              }
              else if(outcome.current === 'userBW' || outcome.current === 'userAL'){
                console.log('three')
                winnerB.current = true
              }
              break
            }
          }
          console.log('outcome is', outcome )
          console.log(winnerA.current)
        })
    }
return(
    <>
     ...
     { winnerA.current === true ? 'Winner' : tie.current === true ? 'Tie' : winnerB.current === true ? 'Lost' : null}
     { winnerB.current === true ? 'Winner' : tie.current === true ? 'Tie' : winnerA.current === true ? 'Lost' : null}
```

The problem is that, while I get the correct output, the outcome state is correctly updated, along with winnerA, winnerA and tie. The text in the ternary that should indicate who won is not rendered when any of these states change

Comment: If those are `useRef`s that should be included in the question--there's nothing here that deals with state explicitly. Where/how are the `current`s set back to false? There's a lot of missing context here.

Comment: Changing a ref **do not** trigger a rerender. Use `useState` instead